Why are there no "length" and "precision" fields in DBeaver Properties Editor?
DBeaver Properties Editor view
DBeaver version is 24.2.0.
It's a community version.
I want to set the length and precision of datatype，but I can't find the fields.
I haven't set anything, they are all default options.
How can I set them to be displayed?

Maybe part of data type? varchar(13), number(6, 2)

@JoopEggen thx , but data type is a drop-down menu with no length or prec.

Integer column highlighted does not have any length or precision property either (used to have length, but that was deprecated luckily)
